# Group data by 5 minute time intervals, SQL

Tags: sql

I have some difficulties in getting the correct result with this query. 
I have a data with information of every 30 seconds and I want to divide the time into 5-minute blocks to shrink the size of the data. 
I have to take the average of one of the features of samples in each group and sum of one of the other features.
I appreciate it if you could help me to understand why it does not work correctly.

```
INSERT INTO filee.ex_data
SELECT a.id AS id,
avg(CAST(a.feat1 as smallint)) AS feat1,
sum(CAST(a.feat2 as smallint)) AS feat2,
a.day AS day,
avg(hour(a.date_and_time)*60 + minute(a.date_and_time)) AS hr_min
FROM filex.my_data a
WHERE a.year=2019 AND a.month=2 
GROUP BY (hour(a.date_and_time)*60 + minute(a.date_and_time)) / 5, day, id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a single `id` value for each grouped set of records without some aggregation (min, max, avg or otherwise), but here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
select 
    min(a.id) as id_start,
    avg(a.id) as id_avg,
    max(a.id) as id_end,
    dateadd(second,datediff(second,min(a.date_and_time),max(a.date_and_time))/2,min(a.date_and_time)) as datetime_midpoint,
    avg(a.feat1) as avgFeat1,
    sum(a.feat2) as sumFeat2
from my_data a
group by 
    datepart(year, a.date_and_time),
    datepart(month, a.date_and_time),
    datepart(day, a.date_and_time),
    datepart(hour, a.date_and_time),
    datepart(minute, a.date_and_time) / 10
order by 1
```

This gives you results like:

```
/----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| id_start | id_avg | id_end |    datetime_midpoint    | avgFeat1 | sumFeat2 |
|----------|--------|--------|-------------------------|----------|----------|
|     1    |   10   |   20   | 2020-01-01 00:04:45.000 |    58    |   1085   |
|    21    |   30   |   40   | 2020-01-01 00:14:45.000 |    37    |    584   |
|    41    |   50   |   60   | 2020-01-01 00:24:45.000 |    38    |    943   |
|    61    |   70   |   80   | 2020-01-01 00:34:45.000 |    46    |   1185   |
|    81    |   90   |  100   | 2020-01-01 00:44:45.000 |    47    |    913   |
|   101    |  110   |  120   | 2020-01-01 00:54:45.000 |    44    |   1151   |
|   121    |  130   |  140   | 2020-01-01 01:04:45.000 |    62    |   1079   |
|   141    |  150   |  160   | 2020-01-01 01:14:45.000 |    37    |   1093   |
|   161    |  170   |  180   | 2020-01-01 01:24:45.000 |    39    |   1027   |
|   181    |  190   |  200   | 2020-01-01 01:34:45.000 |    59    |   1046   |
|   201    |  210   |  220   | 2020-01-01 01:44:45.000 |    53    |   1107   |
\----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The data of each day and id should be separated. The goal is to shrink the size of data. My data has records of every 30 seconds at each id for 30 days and I want to reduce the size of data by 10 by using 5 minute intervals.

Comment: What I've detailed combines batches of 20 records (10 minutes if each record is arriving at 30 second intervals) into a single record, so if you want to batch in 5 minute intervals instead of 10 minutes, just switch out the `/ 10` for `/ 5` in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: So, the dummy dataset I used above contained 220 records, but the query I've detailed "shrinks" this as you put it to just the 11 records you see in my example output - this is what you've asked for, isn't it?

Comment: If not, you'll need to provide some actual input data and expected output to help people understand what you're trying to achieve.